# How to install puny_mce editor for Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

It seems the puny_mce project hasn't been updated for Rails 3. Anyone help me to get it running? I want to have a very simple editor, and I don't need all the attachment features of tiny_mce.

The error I get is:

```
$ rails plugin install git://github.com/imanel/puny_mce.git
$ rake puny_mce:install
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/01/04/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /data/rails/tracker/Rakefile:7)
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'puny_mce:install'
```

Under `vendor/plugins/puny_mce`:

```
./init.rb <-- ActionView::Base.send :include, PunyMCE
./lib/puny_mce.rb <-- module PunyMCE
./public/javascripts <-- all the js/css/images/html etc
./tasks/puny_mce.rake <-- the rake installer script
```

Can someone explain the steps? Or how I can update the rake install script for it?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this last night and the following process worked.
I did not run the install rake task but just copied the required assetts from the plugin directory to the /assets directory (as opposed to the public/javascripts directory.

ie copy the directory /vendor/plugins/puny_mce/public/javascripts/punymce 
to /assets/punymce

Then edit the file vendor/plugins/puny_mce/lib/puny_mce.rb

at the bottom of the include_puny_mce method is the line;
javascript_include_tag include_array

This does not work in Rails 3 as the javascript_include_tag doesnt seem to cope with an array of files to include.

I modified the file to run the javascript_include_tag method multiple times and return the concatenated result. This still failed.

Finally I discovered that javascript_include tag was returning an "ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer" (whatever that is, I have not used Rails 3 before for this very sort of reason and lack of backwards compatibility).
So I simply converted the String result into one of these and it worked.

The code that works is to replace:

```
javascript_include_tag include_array
```

with

```
tags=Array.new
include_array.each do |a| 
  tags.push(javascript_include_tag(a))
end
tag =tags.join(" ")

t=ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer.new(tag)  
return t
```

I'm sure there is a more elegant way but this change certainly gets it working but as a first go this certainly worked on Rails 3.2.2

Cheers
George